# Search a text string with a Lucene query in Java

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I would like to search a normal Java string using a Lucene query string and get a result telling me if there is a match or not. Something like:

```
luceneQueryString("t?st", "this is a test ...");
```

should return true. I found **[this](http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/)** that I could use if it wasn't written for an old Lucene version.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curios, wouldn't it be better to use regex instead of Lucene in this case?

Comment: Hi Vahid. The reason for using Lucene is that I want to find which fields that matched a lucene query-string query made in Elasticsearch. I have not found any other way to achieve this. Only the documents containing the match is returned (obviously), but no information about which field was actually matching.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good description myself **[here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)**.